# Game tie probability

Tags: probability, game-theory

If we have 3 players, playing extreme RPS game like image below:

[image]

How much tie probabilities?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give more details on the rules of the game?

Comment: it's rock-paper-scissor, but more complicated, with 25 weapon.

if you want to know easier game, try this :
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/ad/Pierre_ciseaux_feuille_l%C3%A9zard_spock_aligned.svg/600px-Pierre_ciseaux_feuille_l%C3%A9zard_spock_aligned.svg.png

Comment: I know rock-paper-scissor, but for two players. I think you should add the rules for three players, and the exact definition of a tie is in this situation.

Comment: from the image it is not possible to understand the relationship between those actions. you need to specify which shape beats (or ties with).